# Find the most common sentences/phrases among millions of documents using Python

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, nlp, gensim

I have about 5 million documents.  A document is composed of many sentences, and may be about one to five pages long.  Each document is a text file.

I have to find the most common sentences / phrases (at least 5 words long) among all the documents. How should I achieve this?

Comment: You need to give more details, and to provide a starting point, we are not going to code something from scratch ;)

Comment: try looking into https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html

Comment: might need to make a subselection of 2 or 3 long first to keep it doable

Comment: As your account is over 7 years old, you should well understand by now that Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service. Please (re-)read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For exactly 5-word-long phrases, this is relatively simple Python (which may require lots of memory). For variably-longer phrases, it's a bit more complicated – & may need additional clarification about what kinds of longer phrases you'd want to find.

For the 5-word (aka '5-gram') case:

In one pass over the corpus, you generate *all 5-grams*, & tally their occurrences (say into a `Counter`), then report the top-N.

For example, let's assume `docs` is a Python sequence of all your tokenized texts, where each individual item is a list-of-string-words. Then roughly:

```
from collections import Counter

ngram_size = 5
tallies = Counter()

for doc in docs:
    for i in range(0, len(doc)-4):
        ngram = tuple(doc[i:i+5])
        tallies[ngram] += 1

# show the 10 most-common n-grams
print(tallies.most_common(10))
```

If you then wanted to also consider variably longer phrases, it's a little trickier – but note any such phrase would have to start with some of the 5-grams you'd already found.

So you could consider gradually repeating the above, for 6-grams, 7-grams, etc.

But to optimize for memory/effort, you could add a step to *ignore* all n-grams that don't already start with one of the top-N candidates you chose from an earlier run. (For example, in a 6-gram run, the `+=` line above would be conditional on the 6-gram starting-with one of the few 5-grams you've already considered to be of interest.)

And further, you'd stop looking for ever-longer n-grams when (for example) the count of top 8-grams is already below the relevant top-N counts of shorter n-grams. (That is, when any further longer n-grams are assured of being less-frequent than your top-N of interest.)